# Set content height to exact font-size

Tags: html, css

I have a text element, like `<p>`. As you can see from the screenshot below, the content has a slight "own" padding that makes it a few pixels bigger than the height of the text itself:

[image: The font-size here calculates to 14px.]

My question is, is there a way to set the content height to exactly fit the text?

[image: The content height is supposed to stop exactly at the font-size]

EDIT: I'm providing some code.

```css
p {
  background: #9dc2e5;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.875em; /* calculates to 14px is em base is 16px */
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  margin: -4px 0 -8px 0;
  }
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
```

Comment: Please add your code so that we can reproduce the problem

Comment: play with your line-height

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

But I would use a class in the `p` tag and set the rule for this class so that this doesn't affect all `p`tags.

P.S.: The border will go to the height of the very highest possible character/letter of the font which isn't always in use.

Comment: That sounds plausible. :/